# Laravel 5.4 did't flash old data

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.4

Good day. I have an issue with validation in laravel. When i submit my form, rules work but validation didn't flash old data and messages to session.
Here my code:

#### Controller:

```php
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {

            $rules = [
                'name' => 'required|max:10',
                'email' => 'required|email',
            ];

            $this->validate($request, $rules);

            dump($request->all());
        }

        return view('contact', ['title' => 'Contacts']);
    }
}
```

#### View:

```HTML
@section('contents')
<div class="col-md-9">

    <pre>
    {{ print_r(Session::all()) }}
    </pre>

    <div class="">
        <h2>Contact us!</h2>
    </div>

    <p>
        This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a
        jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more
        unique.
    </p>

    @if(count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>

    @endif
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('contact') }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}"
                   placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" name="email"
                   placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="site">Site</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="site" value="{{ old('site') }}" name="site"
                   placeholder="Site">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Text</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="text" name="text" rows="3">{{ old('text') }}</textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

#### kernel.php

```php
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

The example below is also not working in my case:

```php
class ContactRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

This example is only working for me.

```php
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) { 
    dump($request->all());
    $messages = ['name' => 'What a fuck'];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required'
    ], $messages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        redirect()->route('contact')
                  ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried Request::old('fieldName');  ??

Comment: @RohitS Yes. But it didnt work. In form i show data in session {{ print_r(Session::all()) }} and its empty)

Comment: hey..sorry for late ans but then it seems like you dont have session set make sure your path has web middleware associated with it

Comment: @RohitS No its not working

Comment: not sure what the problem you are facing i myself tried the same thing and it worked well

Comment: try running composer dump-autload and config:cache

Answer (score 0):

You can use session flash to display validation messages. Flash data is valid for only one time. After one request they are unset automatically.

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Some validation message');
```

If you need to keep your flash data around for several requests, you may use the reflash method, which will keep all of the flash data for an additional request. If you only need to keep specific flash data, you may use the keep method:

```
$request->session()->reflash(); 

$request->session()->keep(['username', 'email']);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes i know it. But I only dont understand why native method validate dint flash data to session)

Comment: Where are you using rules() method?

Comment: First time in my controller(look at top). Second time with Class ContactRequest , I did not show this example, because the situation there is the same.

Comment: The rules in your ContactController is an array while the rules in your class ContactRequest is a method. I can't seem to find why did that or you need to do. You didn't used that method anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a problem. The error was that if I registered a web group for my routs, then the session was broken. Because from version 5.3 on, the RouteServiceProvider class has a method that by default registers a web group for all routs. And this broke my session.

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }
}
```